# how to search for a line match from all files recursively found in a directory

Tags: php, linux, unix, search, ubuntu

Using linux commands, is there any way to know which file has the given line of code from a given project directory?

All directories are traced recursively for all files in subdirectories as well.

say your project is in `php` and is in directory `/var/www/projectDir/`

and the line to be searched is `public function getProjectData(` to know where (in which file lying in which subdirectory ) `getProjectData` php function is defined?

Comment: sharing as knowledge QA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the command

```
 find /var/www/projectDir/ -name '*.php'|xargs grep 'public function getProjectData('
```

the first portion

```
find /var/www/projectDir/ -name '*.php'
```

will search all the files which are having extension `php` and within directory `/var/www/projectDir`

the second portion

```
xargs grep 'public function getProjectData('
```

will search all the files found in first portion for `public function getProjectData(`.

xargs is used to consider the output of first portion as a standard input for second portion.

The symbol `|`  named `pipe` will pipe the output to second portion

output

```
/var/www/projectDir/sub/directory/somephpfile.php:    public function getProjectData($param1, $param2) {
```

now you can open the file and search for which line the content is defined using

```
(ctrl + F for gedit) or ( ctrl + W for nano)
```

or use any of your favorite editor.

Comment: It's shorter to do `find ... '*php' -exec grep 'public function' {} +`

Comment: `grep -n ...` will give you the line number also

Comment: I didn't find line nummber with `grep`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the shell :

```
 grep "text string to search" directory-path -R
```

**EDIT**: adding `-R` for recursive search

or even better, use PHP :

```
$reflFunc = new ReflectionFunction('function_name');
print 'File :' $reflFunc->getFileName() . ' at line : ' . $reflFunc->getStartLine();`
```

Comment: this didn't help to solve the problem. In ubuntu I am getting error message like /var/www/projectDir Is a directory

Comment: `grep "text string to search" /var/www/projectDir/* -R`

Comment: this one works. When `-R` is mentioned do we really need to mention `/*` at the end of directory path?

Comment: /* includes all the files from the base folder. That is required. Add -R if you want to also search in subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

I go with the below line. It helps me always,

```
find dirname -type f -print | xargs grep -i "pattern" > /tmp/samplefile
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that is as an old question and currently most used IDEs provide such functionality, but when I started to learn programing, one of the first thing that i learned is to use:

```
grep -iRn "wanted string"
```

**i** : Ignore case distinctions in patterns and input data

**R** : For each directory operand, read and process all files in that directory, recursively, following all symbolic links.

**n** : Line-number

More info - [see this](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)